# Local Development Environment LAMP

Tags: dns, homebrew, development-environment, lamp

I hope this is the right place to ask this. I am currently trying to setup my local dev environment. I have been following this guide (which has worked for me every time) to perform the setup: [guide here](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew). However, when trying to open up a local file that is in my `Sites` folder, I'm getting `ProjectName.dev’s server DNS address could not be found.` However, when I `scutil --dns` I see:

```
resolver #8
domain   : dev
nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
reach    : Reachable, Local Address, Directly Reachable Address
```

When I use `ping` `ping -c 1 projectName.dev`. I receive the following:

```
PING projectName.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms

--- projectName.dev ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.048/0.048/0.048/0.000 ms
```

When using `nslookup` `nslookup projectName.dev`:

```
Server:     2001:558:feed::2
Address:    2001:558:feed::2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   projectName.dev
Address: 127.0.53.53
```

Comment: what is the output of `sudo netstat -nap | grep 35353`

Comment: I just get `netstat: option requires an argument -- p` followed by a list of Usages.